# OpenCV - remap() - getting black pixels

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using an STMap to map a .jpg image using `remap()`.

I loaded my STMap, split the channels and converted each channel matrix to `CV_32FC1`. 
I checked them and it worked - each matrix displays correctly and all of its values are between 0.0 and 1.0.

However, when i try to use the `remap()` function:

```
Mat dst;
remap(image4, dst,map_x,map_y,INTER_LINEAR,BORDER_CONSTANT,Scalar(0,0,0));
imshow( "Result", dst );
```

It just displays a black image.

1. `image4` = my .jpg image
2. `map_x` = grayscale CV_32FC1 (red channel
   of the original STMap)
3. `map_y` = grayscale CV_32FC1 (green channel
   of the original STMap)

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that map_x and map_y must be coordinates (locations where to remap to) instead of images? Not sure...

Comment: From looking up examples online they should be Mat structures.

Comment: yes a Mat, but pixel values are target pixel positions. For example if your source pixel in position(100, 200) should be placed to position(300, 400) your map_x.at<float>(100,200)=300 and map_y.at<float>(100,200)=400 or map_x/y.at<float>(300,400)=100/200, not sure.

Comment: Shouldn't the values inside map_x and map_y be of type float? (CV_32FC1). In my case they are, so they only range between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: they are pixel positions and should range (up to) from 0 to imageWidth and 0 to imageHeight (floats are used because you can interpolate by setting to positions in between some pixel). See http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html how they set the map to flip the image.

Comment: Okay.. and is there no workflow for using STMaps for remapping? It seems like such a common image processing operation yet i found nothing about how to do it with OpenCV online..

Answer (score 0):

Black image when using `cv::remap` is due to using offsets instead of absolute locations in the passed map(s).

Optical flow algorithms usually export motion vectors, not absolute positions, whereas `cv::remap` expects the absolute coordinate (subpixel) to sample from.

To convert between the two, starting with a `CV_32FC2` flow matrix we can do something like this:

```
// Convert from offsets to absolute locations.
Mat mapx(flow.size(), CV_32FC1);
Mat mapy(flow.size(), CV_32FC1);
for (int row = 0; row < flow.rows; row++)
{
  for (int col = 0; col < flow.cols; col++)
  {
    Point2f f = flow.at<Point2f>(row, col);
    mapx.at<float>(row, col) = col + f.x;
    mapy.at<float>(row, col) = row + f.y;
  }
}
```

Then `mapx` and `mapy` can be used in `remap`.